# How to load a raster from in-memory bitmap (not from file) into PostgreSQL

Tags: raster, postgresql, postgis-2.0, windows-7, memory

I have a bitmap in memory that I would like to load as a raster to PostgreSQL.

An unfavorable option is saving the bitmap to file and then use raster2pgsql, but as we
have several cameras that produce images at high rate, we can't afford saving them to files just for sake of insertion to the DB.

I'm looking for a solution for loading the bitmap directly from memory. Any suggestions?

I'm using PostgrSQL 9.2 using PostGIS2.0 on Windows 7.
The images are plain gray level, if it matters.

Comment: Did you figure this out?